# Full Calendar event hyperlinks automatically fire in Firefox

Tags: firefox, calendar, click, drag

I'm using [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) with [draggable events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/). I have specified a url in the event object which causes the event to link to a page. Whenever I drag an event in IE or Chrome, the click event does not fire (that's good). But it does in Firefox. There is an event called eventClick provided by Full Calendar but apparently that doesn't fire before the hyperlink redirects. Is there some way to prevent drags from firing the click event without using some jQuery hack?

Comment: Could you add some code, maybe a jsfiddle sample? Did you see this thread: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1523 the last comment mentions to have found a workaround for a similar problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with event.url

Change your event from url:  to hackurl:

And then in your click event instead of:

```
if (event.url)
{ execute code }
```

have

```
if (event.hackurl)
{ execute code }
```

I have the exact same problem and was fixed by simply using a different custom attribute - for now it's a clean and very simple workaround that doesn't require hacking jquery or fullcalendar javascript.

Hope it helps

Comment: This works because the 'url' attribute causes the event to be rendered as an <a> rather than a <div>. By using 'hackurl' Firefox has no href to follow.