# Full Calendar eventDrop firing eventClick in Firefox 15

Tags: javascript, firefox, fullcalendar

I don't know what exactly to change about the following code to make it work in Firefox 15:

```
    eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta) {
        updateCalendarEvent(event.id, dayDelta);
        //Firefox 15 fires eventClick for no good reason???
    },
    eventClick: function (event) {
        alert('event click');
        if (event.url) {
            alert(event.url);
            vUrl = '../Activities/' + event.url;
            openActivityAddEditDialog(vUrl, 'Edit Activity');
            return false;
        }
    },
```

I have done a fair bit of research and this is definitely a BUG. Code works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox 14 & even IE - but not Firefox 15. It's been almost 2 months and no fix is in sight.

Someone posted this about a work-around hack here:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1523

Another similar unanswered Full Calendar Firefox SO question:
[Full Calendar event hyperlinks automatically fire in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923099/full-calendar-event-hyperlinks-automatically-fire-in-Firefox)

Comment: You said that it worked fine previously. Were you using a different version of the full calendar plugin?

Comment: The fullcalendar plugin did not change. I have updated it to most recent as well as jquery & jquery ui - but no change in error behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You will also have some event data like this:

```
events: [

{id: '76',title: 'Hot Shave',data: 'Some data',start: new Date(2012,9, 17, 13 , 55),end: new     Date(2012,9,17, 13 , 115),allDay: false, url: '<someurl>'}
],
```

Change the event where it says "url:" to "workingurl:" and update your eventclick code to be:

```
eventClick: function (event) {
        alert('event click');
        if (event.workingurl) {
            alert(event.workingurl);
            vUrl = '../Activities/' + event.workingurl;
            openActivityAddEditDialog(vUrl, 'Edit Activity');
            return false;
         }
    },
```

That should stop FF firing off the click based on the url: property which then no longer exists.

Comment: workingurl vs url does not solve the problem. On closer inspection it seems the eventClick is not actually firing (because the alerts do not happen) The page re-directs to /MyCalendar/ActivityAddEdit.aspx - and how it constructs this url is a bit of a mystery ../ = MyCalendar and the page is ActivityAddEdit.aspx - but there are always query strings passed though other code. This is truly a ball-splitter :-\

Answer (score 2):

When you include the 'url' attribute in your event JSON FullCalendar will render the event as an an `<a>` link rather than a `<div>`.

It looks like Firefox is treating the drag and drop of the `<a>` as a click and following the URL. This results in the AJAX request getting interrupted and returning `status=0` as documented here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_XMLHttpRequest#XMLHttpRequests_being_stopped

In my case (Firefox 18) this is resulting in a "You are offline! Please check your network" warning message.

Renaming the 'url' attribute to 'targetUrl' causes the event to be rendered as a `<div>` solving the problem. You then need to modify your eventClick handler to use the new attribute accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem for me! Using FF 18.0.2, fullCalendar 1.5.4 and jQuery 1.8.1.

Comment: Correct - it was the url issue - fixed by renaming to targetUrl (or anything but url) - has to be changed in the Json data as well as eventClick: on Full Calendar Init

Answer (score 1):

Even after putting breakpoints for all functions in fullcalendar.js - the error still happens and no full calendar functions are getting fired after eventDrop completes - but the re-direct still happens.

ONLY IN FIREFOX 15!

Also changed to earlier versions of jquery - but no difference.

I have seen some recent posts about Firefox 15 and drop event bugs, but nothing applies to this specifically.

Is anyone out there having this problem?

If not - is there a way to only disable drag & drop for Firefox users?